# Can the permittivity tensor always be diagonalized?

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

For an anisotropic medium, permittivity is a symmetric tensor, with elements as $\epsilon_{ij}$

How can one be sure that it is diagonalizable, if some elements, say $\epsilon_{xy}$ and $\epsilon_{yx}$ are imaginary?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about hyperbolic metamaterials, which sort of settles your second question. It would also be good if you can split the two questions as they are quite different in spirit and it helps to keep the discussions separate.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks for the reference to hyperbolic metamaterials. it seems to adequately point to an answer for the second part.  You could've added it as an answer, I think. I posted the two together because I assumed they are strongly linked. With your comment, I think deleting the second part appears appropriate.